# How to return values from a function which are iterated upon in a for-loop

Tags: python, function, return

I am trying to write a program that will take a user's input (In this case, they pick a isotope from a list), match it against the list, then print the isotope and its half-life. This all works perfectly, except I'm unable to use the half-life that was matched up with the input outside of the for-loop. I tried enclosing it in a function to return the result, but nothing I do seems to work. Code below:

```
i=0
iso = list(["Oxygen-22", 2.25, "Carbon-15", 2.45, "Flevorium-289", 2.6, "Oxygen-21", 3.42, "Nitrogen-17", 4.17, "Beryllium-14", 4.84, "Nitrogen-16", 7.13, "Oxygen-20", 13.5, "Beryllium-11", 13.8, "Carbon-10", 19.3, "Oxygen-19", 26.5, "Dubnium-261", 27, "Seaborgium-266", 30, "Dubnium-262", 34]);

print("Please select from the below list of isotopes:");
while i < len(iso):
  print iso[i];
  i = i + 2;

def search(x,y):
  u_iso = input("Enter selection:");
  for x in range(len(iso)):
    if u_iso == iso[x]:
      y = x+1;
      print("Isotope:",iso[x],"Half-life:", iso[y],"seconds");
    else:
      x=x+2;
    if u_iso not in iso:
      x=0;
      u_iso = input("Enter selection again:");
      if u_iso == iso[x]:
        y = x+1;
        print("Isotope:",iso[x],"Half-life:", iso[y],"seconds");
      else:
        x=x+2;
  return x, y;

search(0,0);
print x,y;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Stackoverflow. Actually you are not saving the values returned by the function that's why you are not able to use them.
If you want to get the returned value by a function, you can save it in two variables and later you can print them.

```
i=0
iso = list(["Oxygen-22", 2.25, "Carbon-15", 2.45, "Flevorium-289", 2.6, "Oxygen-21", 3.42, "Nitrogen-17", 4.17, "Beryllium-14", 4.84, "Nitrogen-16", 7.13, "Oxygen-20", 13.5, "Beryllium-11", 13.8, "Carbon-10", 19.3, "Oxygen-19", 26.5, "Dubnium-261", 27, "Seaborgium-266", 30, "Dubnium-262", 34]);

print("Please select from the below list of isotopes:");
while i < len(iso):
  print iso[i];
  i = i + 2;

def search(x,y):
  u_iso = input("Enter selection:");
  for x in range(len(iso)):
    if u_iso == iso[x]:
      y = x+1;
      print("Isotope:",iso[x],"Half-life:", iso[y],"seconds");
    else:
      x=x+2;
    if u_iso not in iso:
      x=0;
      u_iso = input("Enter selection again:");
      if u_iso == iso[x]:
        y = x+1;
        print("Isotope:",iso[x],"Half-life:", iso[y],"seconds");
      else:
        x=x+2;
  return x, y;

p,q = search(0,0);
print p,q;
```

I hope it will work as you want if you have further doubt you can share with me.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the advice, this worked perfectly once I returned the values of x and y from inside the if statements, after printing them. Doing it at the end of the function returned some very off values for x. You really helped me see the issue I was having :)

Comment: You can use tick to the answer if you find it correct, it will be helpful to other people to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to use Dictionary when you have a Key : Value pair 
Documention on Dictionary https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-dictionary

by the way, I converted your code to dictionary,

```
iso = {}

iso = {"Oxygen-22" : 2.25, "Carbon-15" : 2.45, "Flevorium-289" : 2.6, "Oxygen-21" : 3.42, "Nitrogen-17" : 4.17, "Beryllium-14" : 4.84, "Nitrogen-16" : 7.13, "Oxygen-20" : 13.5, "Beryllium-11" : 13.8, "Carbon-10" : 19.3, "Oxygen-19" : 26.5, "Dubnium-261" : 27, "Seaborgium-266" : 30, "Dubnium-262" : 34}

u_iso = input("Enter selection:");

print(u_iso,end=" ")

print(iso[u_iso])
```

and the output is,

```
Enter selection: Oxygen-19

Oxygen-19 26.5
```

Comment: I appreciate you re-writing my code but for some reason i was unable to print the keys in the dictionary. I think I need to learn a bit more about dictionaries before I can effectively use them. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this simple way....

```
iso =["Oxygen-22","2.25", "Carbon-15","2.45", "Flevorium-289","2.6", "Oxygen- 
21","3.42", "Nitrogen-17","4.17", "Beryllium-14","4.84", "Nitrogen-16","7.13", 
"Oxygen-20","13.5", "Beryllium-11","13.8", "Carbon-10","19.3", "Oxygen-19", 
"26.5", "Dubnium-261","27", "Seaborgium-266", "30", "Dubnium-262", "34"]
print("Please select from the below list of isotopes: ")
i=0
while i < len(iso):
   print(iso[i])
   i = i + 2
def search():
    u_iso = input("Enter selection: ")
    for x in range(len(iso)):
        if u_iso == iso[x]:
            y = x+1
                print("Isotope:"+iso[x]+"Half-life:"+ iso[y]+"seconds")
            else:
                pass (or) print("Isotope not found")
search()
```

the result will be..

```
Enter selection: Oxygen-22
Isotope:Oxygen-22Half-life:2.25seconds
(or)
Enter selection: Iron
Isotope not found
```

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't appear to work around the 'or' statement. I don't know if it's me not having the correct things installed or what. Thank you for your help anyway, this seems a lot cleaner than my code, and i'll try to use what you've suggested in the future